# Pandas unique combinations considering permutation

Tags: python, pandas

So, my data looks like this

| category_a | category_b | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| categoty_1 | category_2 | 2 |
| categoty_2 | category_1 | 3 |
| categoty_3 | category_4 | 1 |
| categoty_4 | category_3 | 8 |

I would like to transform it to another data frame:

| category_a | category_b | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| categoty_1 | category_2 | 5 |
| categoty_3 | category_4 | 9 |

I do not understand how to take into account the permutation of the same data